# VScode cant find Definitions of non-builtin modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am starting to use VScode for developing Python, but I am having some trouble getting some things to works, most importantly I would like to be able to see definitions of functions.
This should work by just hovering on the function (which does work for built-ins, like round()), but does not for imported modules, see the following screenshot:
[Defintion cant be loaded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkp94.png)
For the module itself, I get information when hovering over its name:
[Description is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29lkA.png)

It should be noted that I am using a Conda environment, which is noted in my settings.json:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/philip/miniconda3/envs/CV1/bin/python"
```

"Go to definition" on the function in question yields: "No defintion found for "arange"".
The problem persists both in WSL and Windows 10, with different conda envs.
Is there anything I need to put into my settings I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

the method `numpy.arange` is defined in a binary file `numpy/core/multiarray` and its doc is generated in `numpy/add_newdocs.py` (line ~1321).

It is a known function because it is defined in an `__all__` list in `numpy/core/numeric.py`

Because there is no `def arange()` Intellisense has no clue what the arguments are.

If you try with a different function defined in `numpy/core/numeric.py` like `ones` you get Intellisense on parameters.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be true. 
Do you know of any workaround for this? I switched from PyCharm, which was able to display the right definition (though I have no clue where it got them from).

Comment: @DoubleSteakHouse If they know numpy generates the docs for binary code like this they can parse the `add_newdocs.py` file or they do the same thing as IDLE, import the module and do introspection